# Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, gradle

I get the exeception `Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name....`, when I synchronise my gradle before adding the library `:compile 'com.gjiazhe:PanoramaImageView:1.0'`.

```
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
```

This is my gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    // # global info
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
//    compileOptions.encoding = 'utf-8'

    // #
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.MyApp.test" 
        minSdkVersion 16 // here we target more than 92% of users devices (fev 2016)
        versionCode 1189
        versionName "1.1.89"
        targetSdkVersion 23
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    // # dex options
    /*
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
    }*/

    // # lint
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    // # signing config
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../key.keystore")
            storePassword "media*/2015"
            keyAlias "media"
            keyPassword "media*/2015"

        }
    }


    // # type of builds
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
//             proguardFiles 'proguard-rules-release.pro' // prod
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules-modele.pro'  // modele ..


        }
    }

    // #
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/MANIFEST'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'be.shouldit:android-proxy-library:4.2.6'
    compile 'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.4'
    compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.10.8'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6'

    //pour la vue panoramique
    compile 'com.gjiazhe:PanoramaImageView:1.0'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
...
targetSdkVersion 23
```

should all be for version 23, like:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
...
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: @boris-k you may upvote if you accept the answer maybe. thanks